# Looking for a free online gallery that supports GIF, PNG, MP4 and JPG

Tags: web-apps, graphic-design, gallery

I have used several image-hosting services over the years ([Flickr](https://www.flickr.com), [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com), [DeviantArt](http://www.deviantart.com), etc), and I cannot find one that would answer my current requirements.

As a creative professional, I often design illustrations for my company, and I would like to compile them in a gallery to archive them, to easily access them from anywhere, to share them with coworkers when needed, and to get a clear overview of the direction of my work.

Some of these graphics are animations, some are still images, and some are small videos. [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com) doesn't support GIF, [Tumblr](http://tumblr.com) joins batch uploads into one post, and few services seem to answer my requirements.

### The gallery should have the following requirements:

*-easy upload of several files and file formats in batch (a feature similar to the drag-and-drop uploader from Flickr would be best), not resulting in a "grouped" post;*

*-a home page, or an "overview" page where all the visuals can be seen as thumbnails with a pleasing and visual layout;*

*-few limits on the free version;*

*-full-size versions when the user clicks on a thumbnail;*

*-possibility to download the RAW file;*

*-(optional) comments section.*

***Is there a website that meets these requirements?***

Comment: Possibly Dropbox.

Comment: @Kodiologist I think with Dropbox people have to sign up to view shared folders, right? That makes it a bit difficult

Comment: It's confusing. I think people need to sign up to use a shared folder, but not a link to a single file.

Comment: I see. Sharing a folder as a gallery that is either public (anyone can view but not edit) or private to one user doesn't seem very simple (and it requires every person to create an account). But the other suggestion is pretty nice (Google Photos), I was surprised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about [Google Photos](https://www.google.com/photos/about/)? Granted, you would need a google account to use it, but it does all you want:

- upload your photos (via drag-and-drop or bulk upload) that you can easily organize into albums,
- you get a homepage of sorts for the overview of your photos/pictures with either all your albums or photos,
- the only limit of the free version is the quality of the pictures you upload:

  > Back up unlimited photos and videos for free, up to 16MP and 1080p HD.
- you can see the full-size version of your photo/picture once you click on it and you can see the metadata as well, if you choose to,
- the gallery support .jpg, .pgn, .gif, .mp4 and even some [.raw files](https://support.google.com/photos/answer/6193313?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en),
- you can decide who you share your pictures with and how,
- if you make your album public, people can leave comments.

It might not be perfect but it sounds like it could fit. Have a look, maybe it can work for you.

Comment: I really like that, thanks! Works perfectly